# Mongodb aggregation framework to count distinct array items

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some docs like:

```
{ tags: { first_cat: ["a", "b", "c"], second_cat : ["1","2","3"]}}
{ tags: { first_cat: ["d", "b", "a"], second_cat : ["1"]}}
```

I need something like this:

```
{ first_cat: [{"a" : 2}, {"b" : 2}, {"c" : 1}, {"d" : 1}], second_cat: [{"1" : 2, "2": 1, "3":1}] }
```

With m/r it's quite easy to do (but slow), is it possibile to get a similar result with aggregation framework?

Comment: Probably; give it a try and show what you did as it doesn't seem like you've done much research on this.  You'll want to look at the `$unwind` and `$group` pipeline operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with the Aggregation Framework as there is no way to convert arbitrary values `"a"` to a key `{ "a": 2 }`. You will need to redesign your schema.